# pm4py equivalent for bupaR's act_collapse

Tags: python, r, process-mining, bupar

In the past, I was using the R library bupaR for process analysis. A commonly used feature was the possibility to aggregate activities of a sub process to one single activity. This is done with the bupaR's function `act_collapse`:

```
act_collapse(log, "Sub process" = c("Part 1", "Part 2", "Part 3"), ...)
```

The function reduces different subsequent activities to one single activity, using the start time of the first activity and the end time of the last activity.

For a current process analysis project, I am forced to use Python and read into the Python library pm4py, which seems to do similar things as bupaR in general. However, I have not found any functions to aggregate activities as described above.

Does anyone know, if there is an equivalent to bupaR's `act_collapse` in pm4py or in another Python library?

Thank you.